# The nuance of "ample"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, connotations

In a letter to a university professor, I wrote "as a prominent Japan scholar with an ample knowledge of...."
But in retrospect, I wonder if I should have said "vast" or "extensive" instead of "ample."

My worry is that "ample" may suggest that something is just sufficient enough, not exceedingly good in amount. Am I worrying too much? (which I hope will be the case!)

Comment: I'd be more concerned with "Japan scholar".

Comment: "Ample knowledge" is an ucommon collocation, with no results in the major corpora. "Vast knowledge" is more common, with 8 results in the BNC and 66 in COCA; and "Extensive knowledge" is relatively common, with 21 results in BNC and 115 in COCA. This may mean that "extensive" is the best choice; because it is a common collocation, it is perhaps less likely to be seen as boastful immodest. However, since you have already described yourself in the letter as a "prominent scholar", such a concern may be moot.

Comment: @Catija I thought so as well, but a bit of searching seems to show that this is a standard form of attributive. See e.g.: https://www.wilsoncenter.org/opportunity/competition-for-japan-scholars and https://www.neh.gov/humanities/2010/mayjune/conversation/the-china-scholar . (I learn as much here as the "learners".)

Comment: @P. E. Dant  Thank you for sharing your research results. I actually googled the phrase right after I sent the letter and since it showed such few hits that it made me worried. But your comment and the answer from Andrew have eased my worries.

Comment: @P. E. Dant  By the way, I actually found the Wilson Center’s ad a bit confusing. I thought “a Japan scholar” refers to a person in academia who researches about Japan, not a researcher whose nationality is Japanese. The site is using “Japan” and “Japanese” interchangeably but there is a big difference, isn’t there?

Comment: I found the term used in both ways, along with "Asia scholar". Yes, there is a big difference between "Japan scholar" and "Japanese scholar." In academia, though, and especially in the realm of  study institutes, the use of the country name as an attributive before "scholar" is apparently an accepted convention. Oddly, this seems only true of Asia and Asian countries. "Germany scholar" is nowhere to be found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it's fine.  "Ample" usually means "more than enough".  "Extensive" might have sounded a little better, since it means "to a great extent or widespread", but there's nothing wrong with what you wrote.

Comment: Great relief! Thank you so much for your explanation and reassurance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should lose sleep over this, and chew your nails too.

These are the adjectives you can use when flattering a scholar about his or her knowledge: extensive, vast, wide, deep, unsurpassed, unmatched, unparalleled, incomparable, unrivaled, unequaled.

Anything else is faint praise.

Comment: Darn! I know I should. Haha. I guess I was worrying about nothing. Thank you so much for the great list of adjectives. They will help me to become a better xss kisser!